# how to subtract first value with all the rest value

Tags: python, for-loop, subtraction

I have data like this:

```
   timestamp        high    windSpeed   windDir windU   windV
04/05/2019 10:02    100      4.39      179.1    -0.14   8.53
                    150      2.44      164.5    -1.26   4.57
                    200      4.29      180.9    0.12    8.32
04/05/2019 10:03    100      4.39      179.1    -0.15   8.53
                    150      2.44      164.5    -1.26   4.57
                    200      4.29      180.9    0.12    8.32
04/05/2019 10:04    100      4.52      179.1    -0.16   8.79
                    150      2.15      162.8    -1.24   4
                    200      3.34      181.9    0.21    6.49
04/05/2019 10:05    100      4.52      179.1    -0.17   8.79
                    150      2.15      162.8    -1.24   4
                    200      3.34      181.9    0.21    6.49
```

and I want to subtract the value from higher level with lower level in each time.This is what I got so far, but this one only give me 1 value. Anyone can help me please? thank you.

```
for timestamp, group in grouped:
    HeightIndices = group["high"].keys()
    for heightIndex in range(HeightIndices[0], HeightIndices[0] + len(HeightIndices) - 1):
        windMag = sqrt(group["windU"] ** 2 + group["windV"] ** 2)
        diffMag = windMag[heightIndex+1]-windMag[heightIndex]
```

Comment: Please provide your dataframe as _text_, not as an image. [mre] | [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm accomplishing what you're asking, but based on my looking at your code, it seems you are trying to get the difference between the i-th and i+1-th index in the column "high" and call that variable diffMag. If that's the case you can probably use one of the two methods.

Solution 1:

```
diff_mag = []
for i in range(len(wind['height'])-1):
    diff_mag[i] = wind['height'][i+1] - wind['height'][i]
```

Solution 2:
Use numpy diff.

```
np.diff(wind['height'])
```

I made the assumption you're using pandas here based on what your code block looks like. Hope that helps.

***EDIT***

Okay..I think I understand what you are saying now.

I think this should work:

```
windMag = []
for timestamp, group in grouped:
    HeightIndices = group["high"].keys()
    for heightIndex in range(HeightIndices[0], HeightIndices[0] + len(HeightIndices) - 1):
        windMag.append(sqrt(group["windU"] ** 2 + group["windV"] ** 2))

diffMag = np.diff(windMag)
```

Comment: oh ya, I forgot to change the variable name in diffMag (instead of col, it should be windMag). it should be calculating the difference between windMag in the next level with previous level.

Comment: I got the value but it kind of repeating the value
 ```[0    8.531149
 1    4.740517
 2    8.320865
 dtype: float64,
 0    8.531149
 1    4.740517
 2    8.320865
 dtype: float64,
 3    8.531319
 4    4.740517
 5    8.320865
 dtype: float64,
 3    8.531319
 4    4.740517
 5    8.320865```
the value for 0,1,2 repeated 2 times as well as 3,4,5